# wdio-allure-reporter dependency is not being installed when used with selenium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver

> Error: reporter **"wdio-allure-reporter"** is not installed. Error:
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token

What could be the reason for this error?

I have already included wdio-allure-reporter in my package.json

Comment: I am having the same issue. It's pretty frustrating. Are you using Jenkins by chance?

Comment: No I'm not using Jenkins, but I was able to fix this by separately adding required version (1.3.1) of allure-commons-js to my dependencies. Version got updated automatically causing this issue.